# Как добавить бордер к закругленной кнопке WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Пытаюсь добавить бордер к закругленной кнопке, но результата не выдает. Но если убрать закругление, то все работает. Как это исправить? Использую шаблоны.

Шаблон кнопки:

```xml
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MenuBtn">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#3d0109"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="94,35,94,90"/> <!--Value="94,35,94,98"-->
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"/>

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Background="Red" CornerRadius="10">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10"/>

        </Style>
```

Xaml:

```xml
<Button Style="{StaticResource MenuBtn}" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="10" Content="Play" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource MenuBtn}" Content="Load" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
        <Button Style="{StaticResource MenuBtn}" Content="Settings" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
```

Comment: `"94,35,94,90"` - сразу говорит о то, что вы делаете что-то не так. Отступы не должны быть такими заоблачными.

Answer (score 0):

В шаблоне закругление есть свойство `<Border/>` туда мы и вписываем настройки бордера

```xml
<Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Background="Red" CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Blue">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
```